# InstanceContextMode of self hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in a console application. I have two ways to create WebServiceHost, either I create the instance of class implements service contract, and use that instance to create WebServiceHost, or tell WebServiceHost the type name of class implements service contract and let WebServiceHost controls everything.
In the first way, InstanceContextMode doesn't have any effects, it always equals to InstanceContextMode.Single, correct? InstanceContextMode only works when I do the other way: tell WebServiceHost the type name and let it controls creation of service contract implementation class. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. MSDN [says this explicitly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487(v=vs.110).aspx) - instancing works differently when you pass explicit object.